# Conditional compilation on C++ class member methods

Tags: c++, conditional-compilation

Could you please explain to me why this code using conditional compilation does not compile?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo{
    public:
#ifdef NUMBER
        int number(){
            return 0;
        }
#endif
        int number1(){
            return 1;
        }
};

int main()
{
#ifndef NUMBER
#define NUMBER
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << foo.number();
#endif 
    std::cout << foo.number1();
    return 0;
}
```

It shows compilation error:

```
In function 'int main()':
22:26: error: 'class Foo' has no member named 'number'
```

Comment: Because the preprocessor only goes forward, and knows nothing of C++.

Comment: You define `NUMBER` in `main`, call `foo.number()`, but it was never defined in the class.

Answer (score 2):

As commented, *the preprocessor only goes forward*.

Here are the lines of your code where `NUMBER` **is not defined**:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Foo{
    public:
#ifdef NUMBER
        int number(){
            return 0;
        }
#endif
        int number1(){
            return 1;
        }
};

int main()
{
#ifndef NUMBER
```

Here are the lines of your code where `NUMBER` **is defined**:

```
#define NUMBER
    Foo foo;
    std::cout << foo.number();
#endif 
    std::cout << foo.number1();
    return 0;
}
```

`NUMBER` is only defined once you `#define NUMBER`.

In your code, there is no `Foo::number()`.